# Migrating from older .NET Framework to .NET 6, log4net conversionPattern not working anymore

Tags: asp.net, .net, log4net, .net-6.0

I'm trying to get the AUTH_USER, REMOTE_ADDR, HTTP_USER_AGENT, QUERY_STRING, REQUEST_METHOD like this, works fine in the older .NET Framework solution but it does not work in my .NET6 solution, the conversionpatterns do not convert it to any value, in the database for example the HTTP_USER_AGENT gets saved like this in my log database table: AddressFormspnet-request{HTTP_USER_AGENT} instead of converting it. Is there some other way I have to do it in .NET6?

```
<parameter>
   <parameterName value="@username" />
   <dbType value="String" />
   <size value="255" />
   <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
   <conversionPattern value="%aspnet-request{AUTH_USER}" />
   </layout>
</parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@ipaddress" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="100" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%aspnet-request{REMOTE_ADDR}" />
    </layout>
</parameter>
<parameter>
    <parameterName value="@useragent" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="150" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%aspnet-request{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" />
    </layout>
</parameter>
<parameter>
    <parameterName value="@url" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="4000" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%aspnet-request{URL} %aspnet-request{QUERY_STRING}" />
    </layout>
</parameter>
<parameter>
    <parameterName value="@method" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="50" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%aspnet-request{REQUEST_METHOD}" />
    </layout>
</parameter>
```